# Can I use a single CAT-6 UTP cable for both LAN and telephone which is controlled by PABX system?

Tags: cat6, cabling

At my office, we do use telephone which is controlled by PABX system. I want to provide LAN and telephone connection to a user through a single CAT-6 UTP cable. I know that wires 1, 2, 3 & 6 of CAT-6 UTP are used for data transfer & receive. Wires 4, 5, 7 & 8 are not needed.

Now, if I connect wires 1, 2, 3 & 6 in RJ-45 for LAN and wires 4, 5 or wires 7, 8 for telephone, will that work?

Please note, wires 4, 5, 7, 8 would be unavailable in RJ-45 connector.

Answer (score 7):

I did it by myself at my home with Cat 5e and it is working well for more than 2 years. It actually work because of telephony frequencies don't have enought signal power to affect ethernet frequencies from one pair to another inside the cable causing [Crosstalk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crosstalk_%28electronics%29) (and the vice-versa, ethernet won't affect your telephony). Just pay atention to the fact that it will only work with 10/100(FastEthernet speed), a Gigabit network will use all of your 4 wire pairs.

[Here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Hack-your-House-Run-both-ethernet-and-phone-over-/) is a quick reference:

> This is made possible because of the wasteful (some may say "spare")
>   wires in cat-5 cable.
>
> Cat 5 cable and RJ-45 jacks have eight wires. Ethernet uses two pairs
>   (four wires), one for send and one for receive. Telephones use two
>   wires.
>
> Therefore, you can run both ethernet and telephone over the same wire,
>   and still have two wires left over.
>
> In fact, you could run two Ethernet jacks from a single cat-5 cable,
>   or four telephone lines (though I don't know why you would run
>   multiple phone lines.)
>
> This Instructable will focus on changing wall plates from one RJ-45
>   (Ethernet) jack into one RJ-45 and one RJ-11 (phone) jack.
>
> Note that I have not done extensive testing with cross-talk between
>   phone and ethernet, though I have seen no degradation in the quality
>   of either when both are in use.
>
> Also note that this procedure will not work with PoE (Power over
>   Ethernet) devices. Nothing bad will happen, it just won't transmit
>   power. See step 13 for a possibly unsafe way to keep your PoE and add
>   phone service. Also, it will not work with gigabit ethernet-- gigabit
>   ethernet uses all four pairs. It will work fine at 10/100 Mbps which
>   is sufficient for most people.

Answer (score 4):

Gigabit ethernet uses all 4 pairs (all 8 wires). You can do this, but you will be limited to 100Mbps instead of 1000Mbps.

Comment: So, by doing this with a Gigabit ehternet it will not be a gigabit ethernet anymore, it will be a Fastethernet....

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are commercial adapters you can buy to simplify this (you don't need to make up special cables).

[For example](http://www.htdata.co.uk/products.aspx?product=99&type=3)

[image: Coolport blue] [image: Connection diagram]

Comment: I'm sorry but I need to say that not just because there is a comercial device available on market that will certanly works.... EIA/TIA 568A don't actually approve using the same cable to telephony and ethernet aplications, but in pratice it really works. I mean, the point is, it works due to pratical evidence, not due to the existence of a comercial device. By the way, I didn't know that such thing exists, it is really useful.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick - Will this also have the same GigE to FastE downgrading?